# Retrieving ID of a newly inserted row in Filemaker Pro

Tags: filemaker

There is a service running which monitors files in a folder on a server.  Whenever files are copied to this folder, the files are moved and a record is written to a filemaker pro database through an ODBC connection.  In that same process I need the ID of the newly created row to create a related record in another table (with a foreign key constraint).  In Microsoft SQL Server, I'd use @@identity to do this, in Oracle, I'd use the sequence.CURRVAL.  How would I get the identity field of a newly created row in Filemaker?

Comment: nope. because the fm docs and odbc features really do stink THAT bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not an experienced user of the ODBC interface into FileMaker, but I can suggest a possible solution that might work.

I'm assuming you're using an INSERT statement to get the data into FileMaker, that there's an "ID" number field in the table you're creating a record in, and that the ID field is set to auto-enter a serial number. If this is the case, the MAX function is supported according to FileMaker's ODBC documentation.

```
SELECT MAX (Table.ID) FROM Table
```

Comment: this might work functionally, but There is race conditions in this situation mentioned where if another row is inserted in between the initial write and the checking of the ID, there might be issues.. though if they are one right after another, i don't see how it would be an issue, just possibly.

Comment: I did think of that, but didn't mention it. I wasn't sure if that was proper etiquette here, as this is the first answer I've given. If that's an issue, let me know. I have another idea for a solution, but it's more complex.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately FileMaker ODBC does not have a built in function to do this.  Its a real problem.

The problem stems from the fact that FileMaker doesn't have a built in support for Primary Keys. Of course almost every table has a Unique ID, but FileMaker doesn't have any internal way to "know" what field the developer intended to be the Primary Key. That makes it impossible for the ODBC engine to know what value to give back to you.

What I think most people end up doing in this situation is to insert a UUID of some sort into a new column in the db as part of their CREATE.  Then immediately Select the ID using another query with the UUID in the where clause.  So you have to do two queries.  The first one to insert and the second one to get the ID back.

Comment: FileMaker does have internal ids and it happily uses them, for example, in the XML publishing API. So it *could* let us use these IDs in SQL/ODBC and have a function to return the last ID for the current connection.

Comment: Yes the Row-ID is available even to ODBC, but this ID may change over the lifetime of a solution. In this case, technically it wouldn't matter, but it would concern me.  People my think it is actually a Primary Key, and it is clearly not.

Comment: Well, it shouldn't be a problem as long as it's clearly stated the ID should not be stored. Every other DMBS does this anyway (and, as I said, FileMaker's own XML backend too).

Comment: This wouldn't only be useful for indexes, and it wouldn't require 'primary keys'. Being able to select the results of calculated or summary fields immediately after insert would also be really useful.

Answer (score 1):

Could you solve this by generating a unique ID before inserting the new row and then adding this ID into each record?  This would enable you to identify both records after they're created.

I'd also be asking why you need this functionality.  You're adding records into 2 different tables when a file is copied into a folder.  Obviously, I have no idea what the solution is, so I can't advise one way or another.

My advice at this point however, would be to re-consider putting the logic of organising FileMaker data in your ODBC process.  It sounds like the original record is supposed to act as a marker or trigger.  Can the ODBC process be left as just a mechanism to create a record and the logic of how that record is used be left to another process, say a FM script?

Comment: This is how I approach the problem. I get an automatically generated ID from a master row in a MySQL or MSSQL table supporting the appropriately atomic, thread-safe operation. It's the only real option when the FileMaker niceties of automatic ID's aren't supported via xDBC. (And who knows if they'd be guaranteed safe like as a real db, anyways - my confidence level would be low, regardless.)